# Want to get vat-amounts in invoice table

Tags: t-sql

I have three tables:

> tblInvoices: fldInvoiceID, fldInvouceDate, fldInvoiceCustomer
>
> tblInvoiceItems: fldInvoiceID, fldItemID, fldItemQty, fldItemProdID, fldVatID
>
> tblVatRates: fldVatRateID, fldVatRate

with the following records:

```
1, 0;
2, 6;
3, 12;
4, 21;
```

Now I want to print at the bottom of my invoice a list of total vat-amounts per fldVatRate.
Example:
0 % - 12.00 €
6 % - 25.65 €
12 % - 0.00 €
21 % - 5.19 €
I've try a lot of t-sql statements but never get the real thing. The last t-sql give me the desired outpu BUT the 12% is not mentionde while it is 0. How can I get the wanted output ?
The sql untel now:

```
SELECT [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID, [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldItemQty,
   [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldItemUnitPrice, [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal, 
   [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate, [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal * [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate / 100 AS fldVatAmount,
   [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID
```

FROM   [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates LEFT OUTER JOIN
       [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail ON [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID = [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID

Result:

[image]
As you can see the Vat-rate 6% (ID = 2) is mentioned twice while it shoulde be once with the total of the two records (= 1.725000). The NULL-values are just fine to see the amount is NULL.
[image]

I would like an output like this:
[image]

Comment: You say the last t-sql gave you the right output except `"12% while it is 0".` Can you post that SQL query? Perhaps the fix is a simple edit to that query, rather than "reinventing the wheel."

Comment: At least we need to know how to relate `tblVatRates` to the other tables so we know what to count.  It sounds like a simple `left join` and `count` or `sum` query.  Providing the previous query would also help.

Comment: Just an advice, add a StartDate for every VAT record. VAT rates can chage over time.

Comment: Thanks McNets, nice from you to point me at that, but that was already in my head, first I wan't to get the query to work. :-)

Comment: Do you still want 2 lines for fldVatID and a cumulative total for fldVatAmount on the second line? Or do you want a single line with aggregated values for all numeric fields on that line? Give us an example of what you want the output to look like, would help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly simple then:

```
SELECT 
    [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID
    , [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate
    , SUM([HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal * [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate / 100) AS fldVatTotalAmount
FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail ON [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID = [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID
GROUP BY 
    [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID
    , [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate
```

or with a total rows as well:

```
SELECT 
    [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID
    , [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate
    , SUM([HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal * [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate / 100) AS fldVatTotalAmount
FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail ON [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID = [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID
GROUP BY 
    [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID
    , [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate
WITH ROLLUP
```

Or with the grouping that you are after (only an overall total row, no totals per grouping level):

```
SELECT 
    [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID
    , [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate
    , SUM([HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal * [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate / 100) AS fldVatTotalAmount
FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail ON [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID = [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
        ([HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID, [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate)
        , ()
    )
```

With InvoiceID:

```
SELECT 
    [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID
    , [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate
    , SUM([HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal * [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate / 100) AS fldVatTotalAmount
FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail ON [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID = [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID
WHERE [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldInvoiceID = @intInvoiceID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
            ([HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID, [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate)
            , ()
        )
```

Try to put the InvoiceID into the where, will be more performant.

If you want to also include all non matching rows from the tblVatRate table:

```
WITH Inv AS (
    SELECT 
        r.fldVatID
        , r.fldVatRate
        , SUM(i.fldLineTotal * r.fldVatRate / 100) AS fldVatTotalAmount
    FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates r
    INNER JOIN [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail i ON r.fldVatID = i.fldVatRateID
    WHERE i.fldInvoiceID = @intInvoiceID
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
                (r.fldVatID, r.fldVatRate)
                , ()
            )
)
SELECT ISNULL(i.fldVatID,@intInvoiceID) AS 'fldVatRateID', r.fldVatRate, SUM(ISNULL(i.fldVatTotalAmount,0)) AS 'fldTotalVat'
FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates r
LEFT OUTER JOIN Inv i ON r.fldVatRate = i.fldVatRate
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
                (r.fldVatID, r.fldVatRate, i.fldVatID)
                , ()
            )
```

Comment: Thanks bobbles, but in a comment I can't ad a picture, thats why I answered that way. Again thanks for the additional answer, but my sense of the question was to not show the NULL values in the fldVatRate with the ROLLUP-clause.

Comment: Sorry yes, try that last query now

Comment: Did the test Bobbles, and yes !! That's where I was looking for, many many thanks !

Comment: Works fine, but I was thinking , because the tblInvoiceDetails will have many Item-records I have also set a filter on InvoiceID (parameter @intInvoiceID = INT). Is that possible ?

Comment: Sure, best to put a WHERE statement before your GROUP BY to limit to a single invoice.

Comment: Error :Column 'HJ-Admin.tblInvoiceDetail.fldInvoiceID' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `ALTER PROCEDURE [HJ-Admin].stpGetInvoiceVatAmounts @intInvoiceID INT AS SELECT [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID, [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate, SUM([HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldLineTotal * [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatRate / 100) AS fldVatTotalAmount FROM [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates LEFT OUTER JOIN [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail ON [HJ-Admin].tblVatRates.fldVatID = [HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldVatRateID
HAVING ([HJ-Admin].tblInvoiceDetail.fldInvoiceID = @intInvoiceID) GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`

Comment: OK, but now there is no record anymore for a VatID not in the selection :-(

Comment: The VatID = 1 is not in the list :-(

Comment: Huh? Are you saying you no longer get the total row? I cannot see why this would be. Unless you are still using a HAVING? If so, you won't get the total row as it groups first, then removes rows according to the HAVING. Are you sure your query does not include a HAVING?

Comment: In the last script I get a result from 4 records, the fldVatID = 1 is missing, I think becouse there is no VatID = 1 in the Invoice, but I want to display this Vat even if it is NULL for that invoice. I wan't Always get a result with 5 records: VatID 1 amount, ID 2 amount, ID 3 amount, ID 4 amount and the total Vat-amount. Oh yes, I use only your last script so there is only one WHERE-clause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52937/discussion-between-bencoo-and-blobbles).